# how to DownCasting UIViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

base ViewController

```
import UIKit

class SubViewPost: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var content: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var recommendCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recommendButton: UIButton!

    var postInfo:PostInfo!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

child ViewController

```
import UIKit

class SubViewOne: SubViewPost {

    @IBAction func likeWorry(_ sender: Any) {
        Option.recommend(postInfo: postInfo, mRecommendCount: recommendCount, mRecommendButton: recommendButton)

    }



}
```

and another child viewController

```
import UIKit

class SubViewTwo: SubViewPost {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        recommendCount.alpha=0
        recommendButton.alpha=0
    }


}
```

i want add subviewOne or SubViewTwo

My ParentView

```
var subViewPost:SubViewPost

 if postType == 1{
 subViewPost = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubViewPost") as! SubViewOne
 }else{
subViewPost = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubViewPost") as! SubViewTwo
 }

 containerView.addSubview(subViewPost.view)
```

raise error

```
Could not cast value of type 
'MyApp.SubViewPost' (0x101151728) to 'MyApp.SubViewOne' (0x10114d9d0).

2018-07-10 14:40:56.007436+0900 MyApp[7207:209932] 
Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.SubViewPost' (0x101151728) to 'MyApp.SubViewOne' (0x10114d9d0).
```

how to chagne view controller by According to postType

SubView One have Recommned

but SubView Two haven't Recommend

SubView 1,2 have same UI

Comment: There should be more to the error message than that; Have you set the custom class for the view controller in your scenes?

Comment: @Paulw11 
Add more Error Message in Post

and my scenes have set SubViewPost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UViewController` class for your scene "SubViewPost" in your storyboard is set to `SubViewPost` and that is what `instantiateViewController` will be returning.  You cannot downcast an instance of `SubViewPost` to `SubViewOne` or `SubViewTwo`.

You could define two identical scenes in your storyboard, each with the appropriate view controller class, but that would require a lot of duplication.

Since the only difference is the visibility of the `recommendButton` and `recommendCount` elements, why not just handle that via a property:

```
var subViewPost = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubViewPost") as! SubViewPost

subViewPost.recommendVisible = (postType == 1)
```

**SubViewPost.swift**

```
var recommendVisible = true 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    recommendCount.isHidden = !recommendVisible
    recommendButton.isHidden = !recommendVisible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. When you say

```
storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubViewPost")
```

what you get from the storyboard is a view controller whose class is SubViewPost. You cannot wave a magic casting wand and claim that it is a SubViewOne instead; it isn't.

If you wanted this view controller to be a SubViewOne, then you should have declared it as a SubViewOne *in the storyboard* in the Identity inspector.

---

I think I see what you are trying to do, and why you are confused about why you can't do it this way.

What's in the storyboard is an *instance*, not a class. Yes, it is an instance of some class, but it is an instance of that class. So when you design the interface in the storyboard, you are designing the interface associated *with that one instance* of that one class.

If your goal is to have a *single interface associated with multiple classes*, the interface must be generated *in code* or loaded from a View *.xib* file — not designed in a storyboard.

---

However, you would be better off not trying to use subclassing in this situation in the first place. What I do in a similar situation is give my view controller an enum property that says which "kind" of view controller it is, and obey accordingly in code. That a way, a single class serves multiple purposes.

Comment: same UI , diffrent class i can't?

Comment: What's in the storyboard is an _instance_, not a class. Yes, it is an instance of some class, but it is an instance of that class. So when you design the interface in the storyboard, you are designing the interface associated _with that one instance_ of the class. If your goal is to have a single interface associated with multiple classes, the interface must be generated _in code_ or as a View _.xib_ file — not in a storyboard. — I'll add that to my answer.